# How to have a Dynamics CRM with an expired refresh token

Tags: dynamics-365, refresh-token, createuser

For a QA test I need a Dynamics CRM with an expired refresh token.
How can I achieve that?

I tried:
Creating a new user in a CDX environment to be a non-interactive user, but the user is not showing in D365.
Did research and learned that it's not possible to create a policy for a refresh token to expire. Though I believe I read it can expire.